# Denied updating a field that is modified within a BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 4 columns:

- ID
- FirstName
- LastName
- Synced

If row contains synced information, then `Synced` is 1, otherwise 0.

I have a BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER to catch when FirstName or LastName is modified to change `Synced` from 1 to 0:

```
BEGIN

IF 
    NEW.FirstName <=> OLD.FirstName OR
    NEW.LastName <=> OLD.LastName
    THEN
        SET NEW.`Synced` = 0;
END IF;

END
```

The trigger works as expected, if row modified, then `Synced` = 0, but I cannot update `Synced` value to 1.

If I run:

```
UPDATE `x` SET `Synced` = 1 WHERE `ID` = 4367
```

I got 0 affected rows, 0 errors.

Comment: You must use non-equal operators (`<>` or `!=`) instead of safe compare (`<=>`). In current state you set Synced to 0 if at least one of FirstName,LastName is NOT changed.

Comment: TRIGGER is checking if FirstName or LastName were changed and with <=> is also checking if new values are null or come from null to change `Synced` = 0, isn't it?

Comment: **IS NOT**. Operator `<=>` compares two values and returns True if one of: 1) they are equal; 2) both are NULLs. Whereas `<>` returns True in the first case and False in the second case (rather it returns NULL treated as False). To check values are not equal you must use non-equal operator as written above. Plus (if needed) additional check both old and new vales are NULLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is inverted.  You are setting synced to 0 if either column is **not** changed.  The correct expression:

```
IF 
    NOT(NEW.FirstName <=> OLD.FirstName) OR
    NOT(NEW.LastName <=> OLD.LastName)
    THEN
```

The `<=>` operator is an equality comparison that considers nulls to be equivalent.

Comment: What? I'm confused right now

Comment: Your code is forcing synched = 0 if the firstname and lastname columns are **not** changed by the update (if old equals new).  You need to be testing *IF NOT(old equals new)*... `<=>` tests *equality*, not *inequality*.

Comment: Okay, now I understand